# making synchronous request in Ajax, for jQuery 1.8

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, twitter

I read most of the questions asked by lot of people, but as suggested in documentation of jQuery 1.8.X async: false is deprecated.

USE CASE: 
I want to get all the tweets (Using twitter search API) for a topic for a location, which I am able to get using geocode, and q parameter.

but I need to get for all the pages as we know you can have 15 * 100 results from the api as suggested by twitter api.

CODE : can be found in here. http://pastebin.com/rgVDQFve

The problem is tweetsPerPage is undefined because the object returned by getTweets is in state of 1 but it should have state of 4.

I am using jQuery 1.8.2 I tried changing it but no effect.

Can anyone suggest something.

## EDIT :

```
function main() {
for(hindex=0; hindex<HASHTAGS.length; hindex++)  {
    for (cindex=0; cindex<COORDINATES.length;cindex++) {
        for (pindex=0; pindex<NUMBER_OF_PAGES; pindex++) {
            getTweets(HASHTAGS[hindex], COORDINATES[cindex][1], COORDINATES[cindex][2], pindex+1, function(tweets) {
                TWEETS = TWEETS.concat(tweets); /*basically I am getting all the tweets in this, I just need a way by which after executing all the getTweets along with their success functions and the callback I get the control to myself which will help me in using TWEETS*/
            });
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
    function  getTweets(hashtag, latitude, longitude, pageIndex, callback) {
    $.ajax({    
            url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
            cache: false, 
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {
                    q: hashtag,
                    geocode: latitude + "," + longitude + "," + RADIUS,
                    page: pageIndex,
                    rpp: RESULTS_PER_PAGE,
                    result_type: RESULT_TYPE
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var results = data.results;
                var tweets = [];
                $(results).each(function(index, tweetJSON) {
                        var tweet = {
                            created_at: 'Dhruven' + " " + pageIndex + " " + (index+1)
                        };
                        var tweetObj = JSON.stringify(tweet);
                        tweets.push(tweetObj);  
                });
                callback(tweets);
            }
    });
  }
```

Comment: As I see, getTweets is returning the XMLHttpRequest object, not tweets per page. Is this intended?

Comment: Yes it is returning XMLHttpRequest Object but if you see inside it, the state is 1, so actually before executing the ajax request it gets returned, why I am not sure do you have any idea, I tried even call back method.. which is not working in my case.

Comment: I took a google search, and the way jsonp is implemented, it can't be done synchronously. You'll have to switch to callback, which you said you tried. What problems did you faced?

Comment: okay I am trying using that, so basically It is something like this I will edit the question..

Comment: Thanks Andre for your help, please get back to me ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, jsonp requests do not support synchronous requests.

But asynchronous request with callback seems to be working, see fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/andreortigao/hAevy/

Code:

```
function getTweets(hashtag, latitude, longitude, pageIndex, callback) {
    $.ajax({    
            url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
            type:'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {
                    q: hashtag,
                    geocode: latitude + "," + longitude + "," + '10mi',
                    page: pageIndex,
                    rpp: 10,
                    result_type: 'recent'
            },
            success: function (data, status, xmlHttp) {
                var results = data.results;
                var tweets = [];
                $(results).each(function(index, tweetJSON) {
                        var tweet = {
                            created_at: 'Dhruven' + " " + pageIndex + " " + (index+1)
                        };
                        var tweetObj = JSON.stringify(tweet);
                        tweets.push(tweetObj);  
                });
                callback(data.results);
            }
    });
}
```

Call:

```
getTweets("#facebook", 42.3580555555556, -71.0602777777778, 2, function(tweets){
 $("#log").text(JSON.stringify(tweets)); })
```

Comment: yes it is working but in this approach i have some problems as I want to write result to a file using local filesystem using chrome, and then read it, as I do not have any control I might go to another hashtag even if one hashtag all the pages are not completed so thinking about other alternatives.

Comment: I agree with you, I am trying out working with message queuing created by BEN ALMAN can be found here. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-message-queuing-plugin/